# How to pass params from previous state to new state in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have 10 similar boxes in my dashboard each are showing different values for a specific device. When the user clicks on each, I have to direct them to new page which shows more information about that device.

the layout of the second page for all devices is the same. I just need to update the $scope.

What is a clean angular way to achieve this, preferably not adding query to the url?

I am using $stateProvider and tried to make it work with onEnter() but couldn't yet.

Comment: Please add code that covers what you've described and/or create a Plunker example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stateParams` should do the trick. To use it you need to specify the parameters when routing. For example:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .config(ApplicationConfig);

    //set dependencies for ApplicationConfig
    ApplicationConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function ApplicationConfig($stateProvider){
      //Define route states
      $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'pages/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main',
        cache: true,
        params: {
          user: null
        }
      });
    }
```

Then you use `$state.go('stateName', { param: param })`, for example (following the previous example):

```
//Inside your original controller
function goToMainPage(param) {
  $state.go('main', { user: param });
}
```

Finally, you access the parameter inside your destination controller by doing a `$stateParams.param`, or, in the previous example's case, `$stateParams.user`.

Comment: thanks for solution. would you add that if the new page needs the user to be authenticated?

Comment: If you want a way to test for authentication I'd recommend searching Stack Overflow and asking about it if you don't find a solution. There are many ways and it highly depends on what auth method you're using.

Now, if you are asking about how safe this method is - you can still monitor the events and use `preventDefault` to stop a view from loading.

Unfortunately I don't know much about security to be of more help.